# Android: Action bar in Eclipse does not look the same as emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I create an empty project in Eclipse

[image]
[image]

Then, I add my code in value -> styles.xml

[image]

The Action Bar show up like this (in Eclipse):

[image]

But the emulator (Genymotion) and my real device show up another way

[image]

Here, Everything I do with the styles.xml file in order to modify Action Bar is worked on Eclipse. However, my emulator and real device are not.

Project SDK from 11 to 21.

Please help me out. Thank you in advance!